# Is $\sum_i \frac{x_i}{1+x_i^2}=0$ equivalent to $\sum_i x_i = 0$?

Tags: statistics, summation

This occurred to me when I was studying statistics.

If we have 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1+{x_i}^2} = 0
$$
then can it be said that $\sum_{i}x_i = 0$, or at least $\sum_{i}x_i = 0$ is a sufficient condition for $\sum_{i}\frac{x_i}{1+{x_i}^2} = 0$?

I have very strong feeling that it has to, since$$
\frac{x_i}{1+{x_i}^2} =x_i\left(1-{x_i}^2 + O({x_i}^4)\right)=x_i + O({x_i}^3)
$$ if $|x_i|\ll 1$ for all $i$, and then,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{1+{x_i}^2}\simeq \sum_{i=1}^{n} {x_i}
$$
but, I want to know if this can be applied even if some, not all, of them are  $|x_i|>1$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=3$, $x_1=x_2=1$, $x_3=-2$, then $\sum x_i=0$ while the other sum is not zero:
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i\over1+x_i^2} = {1\over2}+{1\over2}-{2\over5}  \ne 0. \tag{1}
$$
So the hypothesis is false, $\sum x_i=0$ is not a sufficient condition for the sum $(1)$ to be zero.

*The hypothesis does not work in the other direction, either:*

Let $x_1=x_2=5-2\sqrt6\approx0.101, \ $ so $\displaystyle{x_1\over1+x_1^2}={x_2\over1+x_2^2}={5-2\sqrt6\over50-20\sqrt6}={1\over10}$.

Let $x_3=-{1\over2}(5+\sqrt{21})\approx-4.791, \ $ so
$\displaystyle{x_3\over1+x_3^2}=-{1\over5}$.

Then 
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^3{x_i\over1+x_i^2} = {1\over10}+{1\over10}-{1\over5}= 0 
\qquad\mbox{(this sum equals zero exactly);}
$$
but at the same time $\ \sum x_i\ne0$.